# Trouble shooting like button

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I have recently changed to a HTML5 like button (on an HTML page) - [http://www.jeyjoo.com/](http://www.jeyjoo.com)
For some reason, the button in  not counting.

- The button validates using facebooks own debug tool
- A similar button works on other pages.
- There should also be a larger number of like attached to this URL which have also disappeared, but never mind that.

Comment: anyone please? Does HTML 5 not work with my doc type?

Comment: pheeew is that tumbleweed? anyone please know the answer to this?

Answer (score 0):

I see its working now, atleast on this page : http://jeyjoo.com/blog/
How'd that happen?

FYI - I don't think this OG:type exists : `<meta property="og:type" content="company" />`

...you might want to change it to "article" or "website".

Comment: it could be a custom object type.  you know you can submit your own objects and actions for the open graph, right?